# Receive only last dir name in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a following script in groovy, which returns absolute paths of directories, located in some parent dir:

```
def OPERATOR1 = 'HeatEnergy | 316'
def folder = "C:\\WinPackages-Development";
def (dir1, value2) = OPERATOR1.tokenize( ' | ' )
def finaldir = "${folder}\\${dir1}\\"
def baseDir = new File(finaldir);
files = baseDir.listFiles();
String s = files.toString()
str = s.split(',');
def results = []
str.each{ key -> 
results = [*results, key]
}  
return results
```

The output is:

```
[C:\WinPackages-Development\HeatEnergy\Terminal]
[C:\WinPackages-Development\HeatEnergy\Cashier]
```

Can anyone hint me, what I need to change, to receive only last directory name without square brackets, e.g.:

```
Terminal
Cashier
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hold a `File`, you can use `.name` on it.  But right now you destroy any structure with that `.toString()`.  Just use:

```
def results = baseDir.listFiles()*.name
```

to get all file names